# Joomla include view in other view

Tags: model-view-controller, view, joomla

I have problem with including Joomla views. I have many views in my extension and I want to include another one in my Dialog.

How can I do it?

In my first view I have this code:

```
<div id="modalDostawca" title="Dostawcy">
    <div id="wewM">
//in here i want to include view data/tmpl/default.php

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of extension is your extension? A module? A component?

If it's a component, what you are trying to include is a template for a view, not a view! (the view is the one with view.html.php).  Create a view + template for what you are trying to see. I don't think Joomla! can call multiple views at the same time. If you can reuse code inside models (if this is your concern).

You can also include files the normal way, with include(...).